# How to upload an image to Discord using Google Apps Script and a Discord Webhook?

Tags: file, google-apps-script, upload, multipartform-data, discord

I've written the following script:

```
function uploadImageToDiscord() {

  var link = "https://i.imgur.com/image.jpg";
  var img = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link).getBlob();

  var discordUrl = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/mywebhook";

  var payload = {
    "file": img
  };

  var params = {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    },
    method: "post",
    payload: payload,
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(discordUrl, params);

  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}
```

However, GAS tells me that I'm trying to send an empty message. Can anyone help me?

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYrGA.png)

The error must be related to either the way of me trying to download the image:

```
var img = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link).getBlob();
```

or the way of how I define the payload for the multipart/form-data content:

```
 var payload = {
    "file": img
 };
```

Comment: Post exact error code,line number .. which line caused the error etc...

Comment: It's either the payload variable definition 

     var payload = {
        "file": img
      };

or the way I try to GET the image 

    UrlFetchApp.fetch(link).getBlob() that causes the error. The rest of the code should be correct, because with little changes I can send a simple text message just fine. But uploading a file is where I hit a wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var params = {
  headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
  },
  method: "post",
  payload: payload,
  muteHttpExceptions: true
};
```

To:

```
var params = {
  method: "post",
  payload: payload,
  muteHttpExceptions: true
};
```

#### Additional information:

For example, if you want to add the text to the file, please use the following request body.

```
var payload = {
  content: "sample text", // Added
  file: img
};
var params = {
  method: "post",
  payload: payload,
  muteHttpExceptions: true
};
```

#### Reference:

- [Webhook Resource](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook)

In my environment, I am using such request body. And it works fine. But if in your environment, it didn't work, please tell me. I would like to think of other solutions.

Comment: You absolutely nailed it. I was super confused by Discord telling me this: https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook All it took was removing the contenttype from the script all together. It's such an easy solution and I couldn't find an answer anywhere. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Item I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.